# Is the a type of JSON? What is this file type?

Tags: php, dd-wrt

I have DDRWT running on my router, and when I request pages like http://192.168.1.1/Statusinfo.live.asp , I get an output of this :

```
{uptime:: 00:03:49 up 15 days, 20:03, load average: 0.07, 0.07, 0.06} {ipinfo:: IP: 192.168.0.2}
```

What file type is this? I want to be able to do things such a JSON decode in PHP, but I don't think this is JSON? what is the best way for me to process data like this in PHP?

Comment: It's not JSON, or any other common format that I'm aware of. You'll probably have to parse it yourself.

Comment: That's what I was thinking...

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. The string here isn't a JSON "object string".

Comment: its not a duplicate, clearly not json, so tagging json is not appropriate, if you want to parse the string, why not start with regex, just closed as too broad

Comment: Looks like a fairly obvious key-value list format to me, with keys and values separated by double-colons and presumably `}` (and possibly double-colons) prohibited in values. I've not seen this elsewhere. Ask the DD-WRT developers?